# Можно ли заменить символ в строке по индексу?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Есть какая-то переменная со строкой, в ней нужно удалить один символ по индексу(случайно полученному через `Math.random()` и записанному в переменную), как это сделать если строки в javascript неизменяемый тип. Функцией `replace()` не получается сделать так как эта функция заменяет по самому значению а не по индексу.

```
    var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    a = Math.floor(Math.random()*string.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length);

// String.prototype.substr() - возвращает указанное количество символов из строки,
// начиная с указанной позиции
// https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

// ++N - операция преинкремента, увеличивает N и только потом отдаёт результат

// Т. е. тут такие пирожки: отрезаем часть строки до выбранной позиции и
// производим конкатенацию с остатком строки взятой со следующего символа до конца строки
let newString = string.substr(0, pos) + string.substr(++pos);
```

Comment: Можете рассказать как это работает?В особенности непонятна эта запись:
    + string.substr(++pos);

Comment: @Kardanx, обновил ответ.